# Selecting min date excluding 0000-00-00

Tags: sql

I am running a query in SQL, and I need to select a minimum date that is not 0000-00-00.  Is there any way to exclude this value and choose the next minimum date?

Comment: What kind of database are you using (SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...)? Do you want to select your date from some table? How is the date stored?

Comment: AFAIK default minimum date value in MS SQL is 01-01-1900. How did that value ended up in your table?

Comment: The date '0000-00-00' is not a valid date. However, '0000-01-01' is a valid date. What are you trying to search for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  MIN(mydate)
FROM    mytable
WHERE   mydate > '0000-00-00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(date) 
from tbl 
where date > '0000-00-00'
```

Comment: Thanks, that was simpler than I expected.